# D3 Arrow marker representing Target - Source flow, as opposed to Source - Target flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have been playing around with multiple D3 examples for my project. I have just added the feature where multiple lines (or links) going between the same two nodes are individually shown - using arcs. I took great help from: http://jsfiddle.net/zhanghuancs/a2QpA/

I then attempted to show directionality through the marker attribute, but have noticed that my arrows show the opposite direction between my nodes. For example, if I have a node source A, targeting node B, the arrow will point from B to A, instead of A to B. I have created a simple jsfiddle showing my problem. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/RoshPlaha/5xj4159t/

```
var path = svg.append("svg:g")
.selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("svg:path")
.style("stroke", function(e) { return strokeLineColour(e)})
.attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

    <marker id="arrow" viewbox="0 -5 10 10" refX="20" refY="0" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5Z">
    </marker>
```

I have used the above same arrow functionality previously, so am unsure why the direction has been flipped.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of your `path`'s `d` is wrong. Your definition

```
return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + 
            "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 1," + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y + 
            "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 0," + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y;
```

arcs back to the source (last line). All you need to do is remove that last line.

```
return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + 
            "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 1," + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5xj4159t/1/).

Answer (score 1):

your tick function was incorrect :

instead of this :

```
// generate svg path
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + 
                "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 1," + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y + 
                "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 0," + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y;    
        });
```

try this :

```
// generate svg path
            return "M" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y + 
                "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 1," + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + 
                "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 0," + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;    
        });
```

JSFiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/5xj4159t/2/

Comment: no worries, as soon as i answered I noticed Lars got there before me. At least you've got it working :))